# How to push the returned value from this js function to a seperate JSON file?

Tags: javascript, json, fetch-api

The following js outputs data in a JSON format (I "believe" the syntax is proper JSON format). My question - how can I get this data to be automatically sent to a separate file on my server, e.g. listings.json, each time a user opens the page and executes the script?

```
fetch('http://www.jamapi.xyz', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    url: 'https://theskint.com/',
    json_data: '{"listing": [{"elem": ".entry-content > p:nth-child(n+2)" , "value": "text"}] }'
  })
}).then(function(response) {
  return response.json();
});
```

Comment: Small correction; That is not a JSON but a string that could be parsed into a JSON (using `JSON.parse(<yourstring>)`).

Comment: You make another HTTP request to send it to your server in `then`, then you write some server side code to handle the request.